# Prove that there exist $p\in E$ and $q\in F$, where $E$ is compact and $F$ is closed, such that $f(p-q)=$ inf {$f(x-y): x\in E, y\in F$}.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Here is the detailed problem statement.

> Let $E,F\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be non-empty sets. Suppose that $E$ is compact and $F$ is closed. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to [0,\infty)$ be continuous. Suppose there exists $c>0$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have $f(x)\geq c|x|$. Prove that there exist $p\in E$ and $q\in F$ such that $f(p-q)=$ inf {$f(x-y):x\in E, y\in F$}.

Here's my thoughts.

Since $E$ is compact, $f(E)$ is compact, and since $0$ is a lower bound and so infimum exists, there exists $p\in E$ such that $f(p)= \text{inf}_{x\in E} f(x)$. I naively think I should consider the set {$f(p-y): y\in E$}, but I don't know how to use the given conditions, i.e. $F$ is closed and the existence of $c>0$ as defined above. I bet these should be related to compactness so that I can apply the existence of supremum or infimum of some set at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Let $g:E\times F \to [0,\infty)$ be defined by $g(x,y)=f(x-y)-m$ where $m=\inf\{f(x-y): x \in E, y \in F\}$. Then $g$ is continuous and its infimum is $0$. Hence, there exist $(x_n) \subset E, (y_n) \subset F$ such that $g(x_n,y_n ) \to 0$. The hypothesis shows that $c|x_n-y_n|-m \to 0$. By compactness there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ which conveges to some point of $E$ and $(x_{n_k}-y_{n_k})$ is bounded. It now follows that $y_{n_k}$ has a convergent subsequence. Can you finish?

Comment: Why does there exist such {$x_n$} and {$y_n$}? Also, how can you say $(x_{n_k}-y_{n_k})$ is bounded? And where does $y_{n_k}$ come from? I mean you said $x_{n_k}$ converges to some point of $E$ and (x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}) is bounded.

Comment: Existence of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ is by definition of $m$ as infimum of a set of real numbers. By Bolzano-Weirstrass Theorem any bounded sequence has  a convergent subsequence. Boundedness of $(y_{n_k})$ follows from the fact that $c|x_n-y_n|-m \to 0$  since $(x_n-y_n)$ is bounded and $(x_{n_k})$ is bounded.

Comment: Oh I see. So, the proof goes like since $F$ is closed, there must exist some point in $F$ to which {$y_{n_k}$} converges? If I'm not mistaken, this completes the proof.

Comment: @friendOfMath Yes, that is right.